# If $A=60, \Delta=10\sqrt 3, s=10$, then find $a$ in triangle $ABC$

Tags: trigonometry

Since 
$$\Delta =\frac 12 bc \sin A$$
$$10\sqrt 3=\frac 12 bc \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$
$$bc=40$$
Also 
$$R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}$$
$$R=\frac{a}{\sqrt 3}$$
I just can’t figure out, even though it should be easy with so much data. Please hint

Comment: A diagram would help to define all the quantities: I can guess what most of the symbols mean but what is the meaning of R and what is the meaning of $\Delta$?

Comment: In what part of the world is it Halloween right now?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That’s embarrassing. I didn’t think it was possible to make a type with an emoji, but here we are. Also I am pretty sure America is the only place where it’s celebrated. It doesn’t have any cultural significance, it’s made up

Comment: It's fine :) Although I didn't think it was possible to make a typo in the word typo.

Comment: Auto-correct :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos A = 0.5 =\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} \Rightarrow b^2+c^2-a^2=40.$$
$$\text{Also since } s = 0.5(a + b + c) = 10, \text{ } b+c=20-a,$$
$$\therefore\,\, b^2+c^2+2bc=(b^2 + c^2) + 80 = (40 + a^2) + 80 = 400 + a^2 - 40a \Rightarrow a=7. \text{ } \Box$$

Comment: +1. Yes, but you need to correct the typo ($c^2$ sb $a^2$) in the penultimate line.